# Can I assume an order in a series of structured keys of a python dict?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I have a python dictionary `d` whose keys are formatted date strings like `20101231` etc. Now, when I run `for key in d.keys(): ...`, can I *always* assume earlier dates will appear earlier in the loop?

Comparing dates in string format is automatically consistent with string comparison, which means if date A is earlier than date B, then A's string representation is smaller than B's. Now since dictionary keys are stored according to their hash value order, do smaller strings always have smaller hash values than bigger strings?

---

EDIT: Short answer, **no, don't assume this**. Code:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.date_range(start='20100101', periods=1000)
ts_str = [t.strftime("%Y%m%d") for t in ts]
ts_dict = {date: 0 for date in ts_str}
key_list = [key for key in ts_dict.keys()]
```

Now print `key_list` to see how erratic it is...

Comment: Even if hash order were consistent with string order, that wouldn't produce the guarantee you're looking for. Hash table internal ordering isn't as simple as sorting by hash.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah I just experimented, it seems the order in which Python throws the keys is quite erratic... at least not in the apparent date order. I have been implicitly making this dangerous assumption in my code for a while, sigh.